# How to download multiple files using Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, google-chrome-extensions, download-manager

Firefox had flashgot which added all the links available in a page and you could choose files by type, etc, but in Chrome how do I do this?

I tried Download Master but it doesn't work. Keeps asking if you give permission every N download and forgets a whole number of files in between.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Two suggestions:

1. [**Simple Get**](http://www.chromeextensions.org/other/simple-get/)(alternative to [Flashgot](http://flashgot.net/), Supports *Linux* and *Windows*).
2. [**DownloadAll Extension**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/downloadall/ajffocjdcmpgjmdfdfkdfdbkjafbkcke)(Supports *Windows*, *Mac* and *Linux*).